# Kubernetes AWS EKS: Find out which specific user ran a specific kubectl command?

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks

```bash
    mapUsers:
    ----
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/username1
      username: username1
      groups:
        - system:masters
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/username2
      username: username2
      groups:
        - system:masters
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/username3
      username: username3
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

I get the above result when I run the following command:

```bash
kubectl -n kube-system describe configmap aws-auth
```

I'm using AWS EKS for kubernetes. I have the above users in my configmap `aws-auth`.

Now if a user runs a kubectl command:

1. where will it be logged?
2. How do I find out which user ran a particular kubectl command?

I tried looking at `AWS Cloudtrail` but can find only the event details and not the user who ran it.
I also looked at AWS EKS control plane audit logs, there too I am not finding any reference to the above mentioned users

Thanks